# iPhoneSDK : view is not loading data for the first time but loads it subsequently

Tags: iphone, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to load a UIView with multiple data. The problem is data is not displays in first load but loads it in subsequent clicks. Can you help me trace the problem.

```
FirstViewController.h

    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @class SecondViewController;

    @interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

        IBOutlet SecondViewController *mySecondViewController;
        IBOutlet UIImageView *myimage1;
        IBOutlet UIImageView *myimage2;
        IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel1;
        IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel2;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SecondViewController *mySecondViewController;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *myimage1;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *myimage2;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel1;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *mylabel2;

    - (IBAction)bringNextView:(id)sender;
    - (IBAction)bringNextView2: (id)sender;

    @end

    FirstViewController.m

        #import "FirstViewController.h"
        #import "SecondViewController.h"
        @implementation FirstViewController
        @synthesize mySecondViewController,myimage1, myimage2, mylabel1, mylabel2;
        - (IBAction)bringNextView:(id)sender {
         mySecondViewController.name.text = @"Paul";
         mySecondViewController.myimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paul.png"];
         mySecondViewController.statmsg.text = @"Doing iPhone Development";
         [[self navigationController] pushViewController:mySecondViewController animated:YES]; 
        }


    SecondViewController.m

    #import "SecondViewController.h"
    @implementation SecondViewController
    @synthesize myimageview, name, statmsg
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [self setTitle:@"Details"];
        [super viewDidLoad];
    }
```

Properties are not coming for the first time. But are displays after returning from view and then loading view again.

I am loading SecondViewController from FirstViewController.

Comment: You may need to post a little more code than that. The code you've posted seems ok; how about the code used to manage mySecondViewController itself? How is the class allocated/initialized? And how are the member values of mySecondViewController communicated to its view?

Answer (score -1):

Hi I have solved this. Actually I was pushing my view controller after setting up the property and that caused this issue.

Instead of :

```
mySecondViewController.name.text = @"Paul";
mySecondViewController.myimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paul.png"];
mySecondViewController.statmsg.text = @"Doing iPhone Development";
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:mySecondViewController animated:YES];
```

It should be :

```
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:mySecondViewController animated:YES];
mySecondViewController.name.text = @"Paul";
mySecondViewController.myimageview.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Paul.png"];
mySecondViewController.statmsg.text = @"Doing iPhone Development";
```

Comment: The first way is the way I've always done this, and it should work.  You have something else wrong.

Comment: any pointers on what could be the problem? As far as I can tell NIB files may not have loaded the property in first example.